# Using arrays with strings with a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am writing some code to create fields automatically, which will save me a load of time. I have got most of my code working, but I have came across one error with the code, which is preventing me from achieving my final goal.

The code is as follows:

```
while ($i <= $numFields) {

    $type               = "\$field{$i}_Data['type']";
    $name               = "\$field{$i}_Data['name']";
    $placeholder        = "\$field{$i}_Data['placeholder']";
    $value              = "\$field{$i}_Data['value']";

    echo '<input type="'.$type.'" name="'.$name.'" placeholder="'.$placeholder.'" value="'.$value.'">';

    $i++;

}
```

The $numFields variable is defined at the top of my script, and I have worked out that it is something to do with how I am setting the variables $type, $name etc.

The end result is to create inputs depending on properties set in variables at the top of the script, The only issue I am having is with the settings of the variables, as said above.

If any extra code/information is needed, feel free to ask.

Thank you.

NOTE - There is no physical PHP error, it's purely an error with this:

```
"\$field{$i}_Data['value']";
```

Comment: do you have n array named `field1_Data` with a variable of `type` ?

Comment: What did your error say exactly?

Comment: There is no physical PHP error, it's just that all fields created are text, and their names, values and placeholders are all "$field_Data[""]" with their alterations for each variable. I just wanted to know how I would join the array name with the $i variable to allow the multiple field process.

Comment: @Dagon, I have the correct variables, It's just an issue with how I am trying to get the value: "\$field{$i}_Data['value']";

Comment: well i mjust confused and know thers got to be a better approach

Comment: if you made $1 an actual array key, this would be so simple. your making this a lot harder on yourself than you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways we could write this one out, but they are all extensions of variable expansion and/or variable-variables.

Basically, we just need to put the variable name in a string and then use that string as the variable (much like you're currently doing with `$i` inside the string):

```
$type = ${"field{$i}_Data"}['type'];
$name = ${"field{$i}_Data"}['name'];
// ...
```

However, if you don't mind an extra variable, this can be written more cleanly by saving it like so:

```
$data = ${"field{$i}_Data"};
$type = $data['type'];
$name = $data['name'];
// ...
```

Comment: Working perfectly now! Much appreciated.